# How to query a List in ISAR Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-isar

I'm new to flutter and Isar. I have the following class

```
@collection
class RootWord {
  Id id = Isar.autoIncrement;

  @Index()
  late int subCategoryId;

  late String name;
  late List<Word> wordList;
  late bool hide;
}
```

I have a collection of RootWords and I'm trying to find all the RootWords that contain a certain Word in RootWord.wordList. I'm not familiar with quering lists in Isar so obviously my code is all wrong.

```
List<RootWord> findRootWords({required Isar isar, required String str) {
    return isar.rootWords.filter().wordListElement((q) =>  q.engWordContains(str, caseSensitive: false));
}
```

Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
List<RootWord> findRootWords({required Isar isar, required String searchStr}) {
    return(isar.rootWords.filter().wordListElement((q) => q.engWordContains(searchStr, caseSensitive: false)).findAllSync());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also recently started learning Isar. To begin with, make the Word class a separate collection, and then add IsarLink to the RootWord as in the [documentation](https://isar.dev/links.html#isarlink). After that you will be able to [make queries](https://isar.dev/queries.html#filters)

Comment: see my answer above

Comment: Then I don't understand what the essence of the question is, if everything works for you

Comment: I asked the question because I did not know how to query the List in Isar. But I figured it out afterwards and posted an answer so it may help someone in the future.